# Phonegap 3.5.0 Cordova Access to application folder after build app

Tags: android, ios, file, cordova

After building the application using Phonegap Build for `iOS` and `Android`, we want to update some files from online to local application files, i.e. we want to download images from online to the `images` folder into the application.The application contains folders like the below: `js/, images/, css/,...`. So using cordova File API, the `fileSystem.root.fullPath` returned the `'/'`, base root of Files stored on the device, i.e. `/Download, /viber, /media, /Pictures, /WhatsApp, ...`. Also, the `cordova.file.applicationDirectory` returned the application directory of the istallation, which not included the files of the application!

The question is how to proceed to get access to the root of `images` folder into the application? The application read from images from images folder, so we need to update files into this folder...

Thank you for your cooperation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application folder itself is read-only (as the File plugin says on it's [documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md)) as it is the installed package. You can access it with the `cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory` on Android and `cordova.file.applicationDirectory` on iOS with appending the correct path such as `www/images/` after it.

You want to store your downloaded files to somewhere like `cordova.file.externalDataDirectory` on Android and `cordova.file.documentsDirectory` on iOS and then use those files within your application.

Comment: Ok, but all images in the application has specific path, like <img src='images/news/demo_news.png' />, and other place like <img src='images/products/demo_product.png' />, so how can we modify the path with cordova.file.* after download from online?

Comment: When you store the files to the file system, they get a new URL on local device which you need to update for the images src.

Comment: Yes, i understood. I wanted the img path to not be affected. But it's fine (but it's not possibl). Thank you.

Comment: After multiple tests, It's fine for Android but not working for iOS!